# Botones en ionic con mismo tamaño

Tags: ionic

Basicamente lo que quiero es tener unos botones que tienen una imagen y un texto, las imagenes tienen el mismo tamaño son png pero como se ve en la imagen varia mucho de acuerdo al texto que poseen.

```css
    .boton_personalizado {
        text-decoration: none;
        padding: 10px;
        font-weight: 600;
        font-size: 20px;
        color: #ffffff;
        background-color: #1883ba;
        border-radius: 6px;
        border: 2px solid #0016b0;
    }
    .boton_personalizado:hover {
        color: #1883ba;
        background-color: #ffffff;
    }
```

```html
            <ion-row align-item-center>
                <ion-col *ngFor="let item of misoficios" col-6 col-md align-self-center class="animated slideInUp">
                    <button class="boton_personalizado" (click)="openDetallesPage(item)">   

                    <img src="assets/imgs/{{item.nombre}}.png" />  
                    {{ item.nombre }}
                    <!-- {{ item | json}}-->
                    </button>
                </ion-col>
            </ion-row>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: revisa que todas tus imagenes tengan el mismo tamaño

Answer (score 0):

Debes de dar un formato adecuado tambien a la etiqueta img. Te está poniendo las dimensiones de cada imagen con sus dimensiones originales:

```
.img{
  height: ....;
  width: ....;
}
```